# IIS Express (WebMatrix) open for outside connections

Tags: asp.net, iis, webmatrix

I've already enabled firewall rules for IIS Express (HTTP Traffic In) and IIS Express (HTTPS Traffic In) on ports 80 and 2012 (this one is used in WebMatrix), but I can't connect to the server from my LAN. WebMatrix is running on a virtual Windows 7 machine.

Is this a limit of IIS Express?> Yes - you can redistribute IIS Express with your applications.  There are no connection limits.
[ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)

Comment: This is really a sever configuration question and thus you'll probably get a better answer on serverfault..

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but while stackoverflow is much bigger I first tried here. Is there any way to quick-move this question to other stack exchange?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request

Answer (score 3):

It is possible though it takes some effort, there's a great blog post on this [here](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx) and Vaidy talks about IIS Developer Express on the  CodeCast podcast [here](http://www.code-magazine.com/codecast/index.aspx?messageid=9a9c9f7b-0c03-47ab-8465-579228a42354).

Answer (score 1):

Is it listening on local ports only, i.e. do you see `127.0.0.1:80` not `0.0.0.0:80` on `netstat -an`?

I haven't played with IIS Express yet so I don't know what the default is or how to configure this.

Comment: With netstat -an I see only 0.0.0.0:80...and it's not working. What could I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying your same configuration and was unsuccessful in opening the Windows 7 firewall to just IIS Express.  I was successful by opening the port I was using (80) to any application rather than restricting to just one application.  My guess is that IIS Express goes through a service (HTTP.SYS?) and that needs to be allowed but I have not yet researched that.