# IISExpress returns a 503 error from remote machines

Tags: iis-express

I'm attempting to test a website I have running in a local IISExpress instance with some other machines / devices on my local network.  I am running Win7 Pro.

When I first attempt to browse to my machine from another machine on my local network segment, I get a 400 error: Hostname is invalid.

I understand that I need to grant remote access to the ACL with a command on the elevated command prompt like:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://mymachinename:50333/ user=everyone`

Now I get a 503 service is unavailable error.

Windows Firewall is currently shut off, and I am able to browse my local IISExpress instance with the address `http://localhost:50333`

What is the final piece to this configuration puzzle?

Comment: What happens if you browse to `http://mymachinename:50333/ ` from *your* computer?

Comment: The problem has been resolved.  See the accepted answer from vikomall

Comment: Deeper discussion of this here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: You can install our free VS extension 'Conveyor' to get around this issue https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score 280, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a binding information entry in applicationhost.config file.

1. Open your applicationhost.config file. Possible locations are:

   - `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`
   - `$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` (VS2015)
   - Failing that, inspect the output from `iisexpress.exe` to be sure.
2. Locate your WebSite entry and **add** following binding with your machine name.

   ```
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":50333:your-machine-name" />
   ```
3. Restart IIS Express

Comment: Hooray! After almost 2 hours trying to get it working between a Windows 7 virtual machine running under Parallels Desktop 6 and my Mac OS host, I finally got it working. I was missing this final piece in the puzzle. Awesome. Now I can test my ASP.NET MVC 3 site running in IIS Express in Mac OS too.

Comment: Just to mention: this post provided a good amount of info related to the configuration I needed: http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

Comment: Never mind.  Visual Studio created a duplicate config entry for the item.  I removed it and it worked.

Comment: IIS Express doesn't always use the config file at that path. Read the output from `iisexpress.exe` carefully to see which config file it is using.

Comment: Key point item 3, restart IIS Express! Locate the icon in your system-tray and stop it to force it to restart. Not sure if there is a more elegant way. But this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: And another reason, HTTPS ports must be in the range of 44300-44399 to use the self-signed certificate provided by IIS express. In other words port 44900 will not work without additional configuration. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express

Comment: If you are too lazy to add every hostname/ipaddress combination use a * instead of "your-machine-name"

Comment: Launching from command prompt, I found that when I used the /path option in iisexpress.exe instead of /config, IIS Express would make a copy of my config and change the binding to localhost.

Comment: For me, `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5001:*" />` worked. I used `ngrok http 5001` to create the tunnel.

The key piece for me was modifying the config here: `$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

Comment: One more hint: If you right-click on IISExpress' systray icon, you can select "Show all applications" which will open up a dialog showing all applications you're currently running locally. Right-click on the desired application (don't left-click or it will open the browser), then you will see "Path" and "Config" below. Left-Click on "Config" and it will open up the related Applicationhost.config file where you need to add/edit the bindings as described above. That is an easy way to locate the current configuration.

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 and IIS Express applicationhost.config file's location was: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Comment: applicationhost.config also can live in `$(solutionDir)\.vs\Core\config\applicationhost.config`. I had to update this one before the 503 went away

Comment: After following your instructions from Visual Studio Debug IIS, my site down and even after reverting it is not coming up

Answer (score 35):

There was only 1 thing that worked for me.

using `*:portnumber:*` was no good.  Yes, after doing that and making sure the Windows Firewall was open, I could connect to the port, but I still got the "503" error.

I tested a few things locally, and discovered that only http://localhost worked.  Using the real IP address (not 127.0.0.1, but, for instance, 192.168.1.50), still returned a 503 even on the local machine. I tried using the real host name in the bindings, but IIS Express refused to start.  This may actually have something to do with how the host name was being resolved.  I didn't explore that further.

Finally, I ended up using this configuration:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53351:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="192.168.1.50:53351:*" />
```

In that way, I was able to connect from a remote machine using `http://192.168.1.50:53351`.

Comment: I hit this exact error, but did not want to hard-code the current IP into the config, since it can change.

I found the wildcard works on the IP and hostname parts, so I ended up with:


`<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:*" />`  


`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8888:*" />  `


edit: really tried to understand SO markdown, I quit :).

Answer (score 20):

After wasting more than 3h on such a full subject I decided to share my setup with you.
My configuration is Visual Express 2012 for Web update 4 on windows 8. This was my first come back to MS VS since studies (at least 8 years) and now I'm sure that linux rules. On django this kind of setup took me 10min of searching documentation.

1. turn off firewall for testing

   ```
   netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
   ```
2. setup bindings in my case local address is localIP=192.168.1.102 (because links can not contain nonnumeric domain, use it below instead of mylocaldomain.com, see stackoverflow policy)
   in `Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

   ```
   <bindings>
       <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53351:mylocaldomain.com" />
       <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53351:localhost" />
   </bindings>
   ```
3. add autorun for ISS Express start service automatically

   ```
   <site name="NeuronCharts" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
   ```
4. Add some weird rules to http server (I still do not know if this is nesseary)

   ```
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://mylocaldomain.com:53351/ user=everyone
   ```
5. run IISExpress manually not from VS IDE
6. you will see that ISSExpress is registering bindings
7. run browser `http://mylocaldomain.com:53351`
   if it is working then we can add firewall rule
8. add firewall rule

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=53351 remoteip=any action=allow
   ```

set remoteip to any if you want to access you server from outside world if you want to access for local network use localsubnet

8. start firewall

   ```
   netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on
   ```
9. check again if everything is working on local and public ip

Wish you luck

Rafal

Comment: This caused IIS Express to no longer run on Win8 with VS2013 without running VS2013 as Administrator. It's caused by IIS Express now trying to open to external traffic as a result of the netsh command. I also was never able to actually get it to serve that traffic; I'd get a 503. To reverse the problem caused by the netsh command in this answer, run this from a Command Prompt running as Administrator: `netsh http delete urlacl url=http://*:55416/` (replace port with your port)

Comment: fwiw - I don't need step 4 (the netsh call that @Rafal isn't sure is necessary) and, although I don't need the "localhost" binding in step 2 to run the VS2013 projects in my solution, the front end loads *significantly* faster when that "localhost" binding is left in place.

Comment: I found that following the above instructions still resulted in 503 using `localhost`. I found that the guest (Windows) machine name needed to be in the bindings in `applicationhost.config`, and on the host (Mac) the guest machine name needed to be mapped to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`. Only then did a request to the guest machine on the host succeed.

Comment: One addition to step 5.
Use iisexpress.exe /siteid:id where id is the value of your site's id attribute in <site id="id"> setting, otherwise it will start the 1st site.

Answer (score 10):

Found the problem had to do with a bad urlacl mapping.  To figure this out:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

and look for things like `http://+:80/` or the port you are binding to.

Then use

```
netsh http delete url=<the url from the list>
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: should be netsh http delete urlacl url=<the url from the list> , this worked for me thanks!

Comment: This is discussed in more detail on the [msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/02/17/a-not-so-common-root-cause-for-503-service-unavailable/). This was ultimately my issue as well.

Comment: Thanks, the exact syntax is `netsh http delete urlacl <yoururl>`

Answer (score 8):

Nothing worked for me. Finally I found [iisexpress-proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy)

See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33623399/631527

Another solution is `ngrok`

Comment: Amazing! I tried all those other solutions and they didn't work either. "Bad request" or "Service unavailable". Too complicated. I installed the node module and ran it, it instantly works!!

Comment: WORKS! holy! Thank you!

Comment: check out ngrok also

Comment: It SIMPLY works like a charm with ngrok! It is weird having to route first from localhost to iis-proxy and then from proxy to ngrok, but hey, worked!.
For example, I have my iisexpress on port `3028`. I ran `iisexpress-proxy 3028 to 12345` and then `./ngrok.exe http 12345`. 

Comment: @TetraDev, the "Bad request" or "Service unavailable" was because the host header received when accesing localhost from ngrok was not a localhost one as explained [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/03/configure-windows-for-local-webhook-testing-using-ngrok.html)

Answer (score 4):

What helped me, was right clicking the 'IISExpress' icon, 'Show All applications'. Then selecting the website and I saw which aplicationhost.config it uses, and the the correction went perfectly.

[image: IISExpress configuration]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is updating the applicationhost.config file inside the web folder instead of the solution's. The solution config file is the one to change

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Anthony Rizzolo's answer: in Windows 8.1, I had to type like this:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=<the url from the list>
```

For example:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:8689/
```

Answer (score 1):

After solution of @vikomall don't forget to start VS as adminisrator.
This fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me.

I have had two entries in netsh for the same service

`netsh http show urlacl`

[image]

One using a strong wildcard, the other one using a weak wildcard.

Removing the one with the weak wildcard did the job.

More about the strong and weak wildcard in the context of netsh

> When the host element of a UrlPrefix consists of a single plus sign
>   (+), the UrlPrefix matches all possible host names in the context of
>   its scheme, port and relativeURI elements, and falls into the strong
>   wildcard category.
>
> When an asterisk (*) appears as the host element, then the UrlPrefix
>   falls into the weak wildcard category. This kind of UrlPrefix matches
>   any host name associated with the specified scheme, port and
>   relativeURI that has not already been matched by a strong-wildcard,
>   explicit, or IP-bound weak-wildcard UrlPrefix. This host specification
>   can be used as a default catch-all in some circumstances, or can be
>   used to specify a large section of URL namespace without having to use
>   many UrlPrefixes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Http/urlprefix-strings