# Access IIS Express on a VMWare Win7

Tags: vmware, remote-access, iis-express

I'm running a ASP.NET MCV 4 project in VS2012 on a windows 7 virtual machine using VMWare. I want to be able to access the site from my mac.

I've done all the steps stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442551/iisexpress-returns-a-503-error-from-remote-machines) question. Restarted IIS, turned off windows firewall, changed the application config file and granted remote access to the ACL and I still get a 503 error in my mac.

Any steps I could have missed?

application config file is the following:

```
        <site name="prototype" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Igor Popov\Desktop\myapp\prototype" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":50438:192.168.0.9" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Comment: 503 is a server error, are you able to run the application from the server (virtual machine) itself?

Comment: Yes! No problems on the virtual macine

Answer (score 0):

1.Editing applicationhost.config file, your site bindings should look like below;

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50438:localhost" />
```

2.Run your VS as administrator.

3.Visite the site with "localhost:50438" in your mac.