# Error 400 Bad request when accessing Web Api from Xamarin debug device

Tags: android, webclient, xamarin

I am trying to get a response from WebApi application running on my localhost.
I can get it from thr browser and I can get it from another web app.

I am, however, having problem with the same code in Xamarin Studio debugging device

```
var url="http://192.168.2.4:13325/api/values";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{

    wc.Headers.Add("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    wc.Headers.Add ("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22");
    wc.Headers.Add ("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch");
    wc.Headers.Add ("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
    wc.Headers.Add ("Accept-Charset","ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");

    string HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
```

This is the header taken from Fiddler when doing request from browser. The web app doesn't even need those and gets the response.

I am using my computer's IP, because I read, that the debugger runs a virtual machine, so I can't target localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this probolem. It was not related to Xamarin or android, problem was on the service side.

First enable external requests: [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

An then edit binding information for your app: [IISExpress returns a 503 error from remote machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442551/iisexpress-returns-a-503-error-from-remote-machines)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem everything  is working good on the browser but connot connect from emulator (i get a 400 bad request) it was very simple i just forgot to launch my web api as administrator

Comment: Keep in mind that android emulators dont have the same ip address as your local ip from your network.