# IIS Express Enable External Request - 503

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I have attempted to get IIS Express working so that external users can view my MVC ASP.NET development website.  I followed instructions on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request) but am now getting a 503 error when accessing the website using my external IP address, localhost still works fine.

My configuration file seems ok

```
<site name="ManagerUI" id="5">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Application Development\Manager\MAIN-Branch\ManagerUI\ManagerUI" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1904:" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

I found the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452471/94278) which solves the issue, but it will ONLY allow it to work on an external address rather than all my IP addresses (localhost, external one etc)

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:your-machine-name" />
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed to solve it, my mistake was thinking that you could only have one binding set, I then setup binding for every external address I wished to serve on and it now all works

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:machineName" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:10.1.10.123" />
</bindings>
```