# Getting HTTP Error 400 when using IP address instead of localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I created a simple Web App with a Rest API with C# and VS2015. The web app is running in `http://localhost:1623` and it works fine.

Now I'm testing the Rest API doing a POST with `Postman`, my url is for example `http://localhost:1623/api/foo/bar` with a header `Content-Type: application/json`. Everything works great, I get the response correctly.

The local IP address of my PC is `192.168.0.174`, so I change the url to `http://192.168.0.174:1623/api/foo/bar` and now I get `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid`, why? Shouldn't it be the same?. The same happens (I get exactly the same error) if I try to access my Web App using `192.168.0.174:1623` instead of `http://localhost:1623` in my browser:

[image]

I get the same error when trying to use the API from some device other device in my LAN using my IP. I need to use the IP because I need to access it from my network, why doesn't it work, what am I missing? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699538/bad-request-invalid-hostname-with-asp-net-webapi-project-in-visual-studio-2013) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044470/bad-request-invalid-hostname-while-connect-to-localhost-via-wifi-from-mobile-ph%20%22%22) with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33243051/1335209%20%22%22) answer editing `applicationhost.config` that in VS2015 it's located in `[Project Folder]\.vs\config\applicationhost.config:`

> Since the linked URL from Jack's answer is currently not working, and
>   the solution (at least for me) was covered in the answer to another
>   question, I will repeat the answer here:
>
> You can have multiple bindings set. Therefore, you can setup bindings
>   for every external address you wish to serve on, and it will work:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:machineName" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1904:10.1.10.123" />
</bindings>
```

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14881682/1335209%20%22%22) was helpful. In my case I did:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1623:" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1623:<my pc name>" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":1623:192.168.0.174" />
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The IIS is a multi web site server. The way is distinct the site is by the host header name. So you need to setup that on your web site.

Please see this link to setup:

[HOW TO: Use Host Header Names to Host Multiple Sites Using Host Header Names to Host Multiple Web Sites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308163)

[How To Use Host Header Names to Configure Multiple Web Sites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/190008)

Comment: I have IIS 10, I couldn't find the `Multiple identities for this Web Site` option but I have this setted in my bindings http://i.imgur.com/HCldO28.png but still doesn't work