# HTTP 400 bad request hostname, while accessing localhost from another PC

Tags: visual-studio, iis, localhost

I want to access to my local host from another computer on the network ! I used my pc's IP and created a inbound rule for my port on windows firewall.

this is my local host address: `localhost:2523/StartUpPage.aspx`
I use my host system's IP `192.168.0.101`
so when I use `192.168.0.101:2523/StartUpPage.aspx`
i get the `HTTP 400 bad request hostname` Error

**Note:** my system works on the local computer with no problem!

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What web server are you using? IIS Express? IIS? Cassini?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I run it on Visual studio which is set to use IIS Express! in other words it runs on IIS Express

Comment: Then you may be looking for [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3364468/477878).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks for the link it solve the 400 Error but it gave me 503 error on remote machine so i used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442551/iisexpress-returns-a-503-error-from-remote-machines) to solve it and now i can access the webapp from both sides only for few seconds and than IIS stops working and visual studio pops up with `Unable to lunch IIS express web server` error

Comment: I had similar problem. Have you seen this solution ? 
[Connecting to Visual Studio debugging IIS Express server over the lan - stack overflow][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan

Comment: You can solve this without config changes using our free VS Extension 'Conveyor' https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti