# Why aren't my networked computers able to access localhost from VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio, webserver

Coming from XAMPP, using the Apache server, I am used to just test my websites in a networked computer by simply typing `IPaddress`:`PortNumber` on the address bar of the desired networked computer.

Then while developing with VS2017, I found out that it is not possible by default. While it works fine in the localhost, any networked computer is unable to access the website. What do I need to access to change the settings so that I can expose it to port 8012 rather than 127.0.0.1:8012 ?

*I assume that's the problem here.*

Comment: can you check in firewall & unblock this port so that other computer can access your web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was able to solve this problem by changing the binding values in `applicationhost.config`
>
> - VS2015 onwards, it can be found inside the individual project folder `%ProjectFolder%/.vs/config/`
> - In pre-2015 VS, its available in `%USER%/Documents/IISExpress/config/`

---

If you are familar with XAMPP, the setting is similar to `%XAMPP%/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

- The difference is that, instead of setting a Listen port number, you have to properly bind the port in IISExpress
- By default, port is bound to localhost for the host computer. Say, port 3940 is bound as `*:3940:locahost`, which makes it only available to the computer running VS.
- To make this available to networked computers, you need to change this section as follows:

### Change this:

```
<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:3940:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

### to:

```
<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:3940:*" />
</bindings>
```

- **Note:** In some cases, `bindingInformation="*:3940:"` may be used instead of `bindingInformation="*:3940:*"`

---

> If after all this, it still does not work, then it may be a firewall issue as @Mukesh pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318052/why-arent-my-networked-computers-able-to-access-localhost-from-vs2017#comment77598079_45318052).
>
> - Firewall issues can be quickly found out by simply pinging the target device.
>
>   - If the ping is successful but the port is not allowed, then open the firewall in advanced mode
>   - Open RUN (Windows + R)
>   - Type firewall.cpl
>   - Click on Advanced Settings
>   - Click on Inbound Rules
>   - Create New Rule
>   - Add your desired port to the rule
>
>     - Port > Specific local ports: `3940` > Allow the connection > Check all (Domain, Private, Public) > Give a name to your rule: `ExampleRule` > Finish
>     - You can replace `3940` with your desired port number or port range. It is also possible to select all possible ports.
>   - ***optional:*** Although nothing really needs to be done in the client computer, you may need to configure your firewall inbound rule to accept all Inbound connections
>   - If it is not a firewall issue, it can be something else entirely. Maybe you're getting a 400 Error page, or a 503 Error. The following SO questions helped me a lot to tackle those problems (although I had to revert the ACL allowance later). I hope this is useful to someone in the future
>
>     - [IIS Express Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646386/5040900)
>     - [Change binding, ACL and Port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14881682/5040900)
>     - [HTTP 400 Bad Request Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19002899/5040900)
>
>       - Solution to this ^ is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364468/5040900)
>     - [503 Service Unavailable Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452471/5040900)
>
>       - Sometimes this is solved by simply creating binding entries in `applicationhost.config`
>       - Other times, its the duplicate-binding problem. And you need to remove a binding entry during those times. If you are editing `applicationhost.config` inside the project folder, then it is okay to keep only one site and binding information.
>       - *for my particular case,* I had to revert this operation `netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.10.3:3940/ user=everyone` with this `netsh http delete urlacl url=http://192.168.10.3:3940/` because I kept getting 502 Bad Gateway error when I tried tunneling.
> - Things to remember:
>
>   - Please remember to properly restart IISExpress after each change. Normally VS does this by itself. Just double check for any running instances.
>   - Also, always run VS in administrative mode. This usually clears many problems and also allows all sub-processes, such as IISExpress to startup in elevated privilege mode to avoid permission errors.