# Accessing localhost from another PC and getting Unable to lunch IIS express web server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, localhost

I want to access to my localhost from another computer on the network ! I used my pc's IP and created a inbound rule for my port on windows firewall.

This is my localhost address: `localhost:2523/StartUpPage.aspx` I use my host system's IP 192.168.0.101 so when I use 192.168.0.101:2523/StartUpPage.aspx 
I solved The HTTP 400 bad request hostname Error using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request/3364468#3364468)
and I solved The 503 error on remote machine using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442551/iisexpress-returns-a-503-error-from-remote-machines)

However now I can access the project on both local and remote system only for few seconds and then get the `Unable to lunch IIS express web server` Error popup from Visual studio!

**Note:** I'm running my local host on Visual studio 2012 using IIS Express!

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This question is for Superuser not for SO!

Comment: Rather than changing configuration, you can use our free extension 'Conveyor' available from Tools->Extension or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score 1):

Your IIS Express web server is configured to access from localhost by default.
You can change configuration or you can use VS Development server.

To use VS development server: 
1. select "Use Visual Studio Development Server" from "Website" menu.
2. from properties of your website project, configure to use static port
3. you can use port forwarder to forward default http port to your server's port