# ERR Connection Refused after adding urlacl rule

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I did a mistake on my iis express, I was trying to enable external reques to my https url.

And I added this rule

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://vaidesg:44382/ user=everybody

Instead of netsh https add urlacl url=http://vaidesg:44382/ user=everybody

But know I have this error :

> "ERR CONNECTION REFUSED"

I tried to set up my firewall for the port 44382 but It still doesn't work.

I use HSTS to redirect all http query into https.

Could you give me some link for documentation, or advice because there is something that I missed.

Comment: I change my port number and now it work in localhost, but I can't allow external request on iis.

Comment: did you host the site in iis or running on iis express? is the external user is from the same LAN or form another network? if the user is from another network you need to purchase and use the external IP and domain.

Comment: On iis express, I was trying to connect an android device emulator to it with 10.0.2.2:port but it doesn't work. I have à connection reset message when I Am trying to connect to the server. It means that my problem is that I can't connect my lan device to my https iis express server (I usé thé redirection http to https)

Comment: you need to add the binding information entry in applicationhost.config file: `  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":port:your-machine-name" />` after adding this do not forgot to restart the iisexpress. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442551/iisexpress-returns-a-503-error-from-remote-machines