# Access website hosted on Windows 7 from Windows Virtual PC XP mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, virtual-pc

I have Windows Virtual PC installed on my Windows 7 machine. I am using it for testing my website for cross browser functionality.

In my Windows 7 I am developing the website in asp.net 4 and VS2010. In my Virtual PC XP, i want to access the website that i host on my local IIS or VS development web server. How can I communicate between Windows 7 and my Virtual PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer through this blog -

http://blogs.technet.com/b/windows_vpc/archive/2009/09/26/networking-and-using-windows-xp-mode.aspx

I modified the settings of the virtual PC to pick my wireless adapter. With this the virtual pc was just like any other computer on the network (formed by my wirless router) and I could access the virtual pc via its IP and could access my windows 7 host system from virtual pc via  host systems's IP

Hope this helps some one.

But this had only one issue - I had to host my website on local iis, allow firewall port exception, to make it accessible to the virtual PC.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, all you need is the internal IP of the host machine and the webserver port.

Yet, since you're developing with VS2010, you'll have to switch to IIS Express and use the following answer:
[IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)