# HttpWebRequest - The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, .net, console, httpwebrequest, timeout

I'm trying to invoke a web page, by using HttpWebRequest, however I'm getting "the operation has timed out error".

```
string sURL = "http://localhost:53667/MyPage.aspx";

WebRequest wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
wrGETURL.Timeout = 5000;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 5000;

var r = wrGETURL.GetResponse();
r.Close();
wrGETURL.Abort();
```

As you can see I added the DefaultConnectionLimit property, closed the response as other threads suggested, but that didn't seem to do it. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

When I use the full example from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023, running/debugging it from Visual C# as a console app, it doesn't time out. When I set this program to run on Windows Task Scheduler, it does time out.

Comment: And are you sure the destination site is running?

Comment: typing the url in the browser does work? And without the page?

Comment: Yup, site is running, runs fine in browser.

Comment: Did you check that your firewall isn't blocking outbound connections from your .exe when it is called from the scheduled task?

Comment: Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall  You could just turn it off completely for a second while you test or make a rule for that exe.

Comment: Turned it off, created a rule, doesn't make a difference. Note, on the same machine it works fine when ran from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple operation give it a run with WebClient instead.

It's much less complex and has less chance of it being something specific to `WebRequest` that is the problem.  Also have you tried running it from the same machine outside of Visual Studio?

Is the site being hosted by cassini, iis express, iis 6, iis 7, etc ? There are special settings for some of those to allow remote connections, and iirc some may not allow remote connections at all.

IIS Express takes special work - [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

Cassini can't do it at all per - https://serverfault.com/questions/82899/can-i-access-cassini-from-a-remote-machine

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code :

**ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;**

Concurrent connections may cause Time out error. In my case, this works fine.