# Accessing web service from another system using ipaddress

Tags: web-services, iis, localhost, ip-address, firewall

I have a website working. I run it and i see  localhost/pagename.aspx up and running. I replace it with my ip address and the port number like this .. ://10.xxx.xxx.xx:12234/pagename.aspx and it does not work. If I use 127.0.0.1,it works.The thing is this web site has an asmx web service. I need access to it. I disabled my firewall.I also added inbound and outbound rule for the port 12234. I allowed on both times. But still cannot see. What am I doing wrong?Is there any other way I can get access? (Some research told me to go to IIS and do some setting changes there. It was not that clear). More questions coming. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using IIS Express?  It does not allow external requests by default.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request

Comment: @Jason. I do not see any word that says "Express" when i go to IIS Manager - Help - About. It says version 7.5.7600.

Comment: @Jason. I tried that was command in the link nevertheless. I changed the path to say h..p://10.xxx.xx.12:12234/ . It said "URL reservation successfully added".

Comment: @Jason. I also added the bindings rule. I gave my pc name and also my IP address name. Did not work. Also, mine is IIS Express. When following that document I looked up and saw that there is a folder named IIS Express. But still no go. What more should i fix?

Answer (score 1):

I want you to follow [this](http://www.csharptutorial.in/38/csharp-net-how-to-publish-a-web-service-in-iis-using-visual-studio-2010) tutorial. 
I will give you  a few steps too.

1. Go to the iis manager and create a new application pool with the .net framework set to v4.0. Also note that the framework of the application/service that you are going to use is also the same framework.
2. Publish your web application/ service into a folder in you file system with publishing profile as "File System".
3. Copy the folder (that you just published) into C:\inetpub\wwwroot (which is the default folder).
4. Open iis manager and refresh the default site and the new folder that you just copied into the C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder will appear.
5. Right click that folder and click convert to application.
6. Right Click again and click -> manage application -> Advanced setting. Find and change the application pool from Default to the new pool that you just created.
7. Enable directory browsing which is on the middle pane.
8. On the left pane, click "rowse *:80 (http)"

the browser will open and you can see the application/service running.

**http://localhost/something/** will be your default value on the address bar.

changing it to **192.168.1.85/something** will also give you the same result. The same can be accessed from any computer in the same network with the ip address your system

192.168.1.85 was my system's ip address. run command prompt and type in **ipconfig** and you can find your ip address.