# Deploy Test Web Application on Client

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web

I want to deploy a test application on client machine but this machine do not have IIS installed. Is there a way we can deploy an ASP.NET application on client machine without IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web server in order to host an ASP.NET application. You could install the lightweight [`IIS Express`](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) if you don't want to install the fullblown IIS webserver. Note that out of the box IIS Express will accept only connections from localhost (as it is meant as a development web server) but this [`can be workarounded`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364468/29407) if you need it.

Comment: Can I use IIS express for production?

Comment: Yes, you can, but nobody will ever recommend you to. IIS express was never designed for production use. Its designed for development purposes.

Comment: I'm worry of side effects of Installing the original IIS on client machine, my concern is security...

Comment: You shouldn't be installing IIS on client machines. IIS is intended to be installed on servers which is where web applications are hosted.