# Can't connect to IIS Express remotely from non-Windows machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I am working on an ASP.NET application and I'd like the ability to test the application on my (Android) phone and iPad by connecting directly to my local IIS Express development server.  I followed the instructions [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) on setting up IIS Express to allow remote connections.  I am now able to view the application from another Windows machine on my local network by visiting `http://my-computer-name:my-port-number/` in the browser.  However, I am unable to view the application from any other platform (Android, iOS, and OS X - tested in both Chrome and Firefox); the browser silently churns away for a minute or so before giving me a generic "could not connect to `my-computer-name:my-port-number`" page.

What is the difference between the platforms that is disallowing me from viewing my ASP.NET application on non-Windows machines?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems I can only connect to the ```http://my-computer-name:my-port-number/``` version of the site via IE, Firefox, Opera 12, and Safari (for Windows) on my machine and on another Windows machine on the same network. I cannot however connect to that address using Chrome on any machine, Chrome and Firefox on an Android phone, Safari on iPad. Have you ever figured this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your devices are on the same network, from the command prompt try `ipconfig` get the IP Address from your wireless and from your device try `http://[IP Address]:[Port]`.

Like in this example:

[image]

```
http://192.168.2.122:5252
```

I am not an expert on Mac but if I recall correctly your issue may be associated with this:

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Mac-to-a-Homegroup

Comment: Navigating to `http://[IP Address]:[Port]` worked for both my phone and my Mac.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between the platforms that is disallowing me
>   from viewing my ASP.NET application on non-Windows machines?

The network to which they are connected. You seem to have mentioned that your Windows machine is connected to the same local network as the computer hosting the web application. But the other devices probably aren't. So make sure that those devices are connected to the same network.

Comment: All of the devices are connected to the same Wi-Fi network, so I assume they have the same amount of access to my development PC.

Comment: Could there be some firewall on those devices blocking access to ports different than 80?

Comment: My MacBook Air has its firewall turned off, so I don't think so.

Comment: Are you able to `telnet` to the specified port from the MacBook?

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but a command of `telnet my-computer-name my-port-number` times out, while the command `telnet my-ip-address my-port-number` (where `my-ip-address` is the IP of my development PC) is successful.

Comment: Well, maybe your network is not configured to resolve by hostname. In all cases this is no longer a programming related question but rather networking administration. You might have better luck asking on http://serverfault.com