# How do you authencate to Azure App Services locally?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps, azure-mobile-services

There are alot of tutorials on how to configure the Authentication properties of a given Azure App Service instance:

[Api Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-authentication/)

[Expanding App Service Authentication/Authorization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/)

There are guides for configuring the Azure Server-Side properties for:

[AAD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/)

[FaceBook](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/)

[Twitter](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-twitter-authentication/)

[Google](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication/)

[Microsoft Account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication/)

I believe these all are setting properties on the server-side gateways that sit in front of our Azure App Service components.  This approach is nice, because you can initiate a login flow simply by directing your user's browser to ~/.auth/login/XYZ.

However, I can't figure out how I'm supposed to Authenticate against any of these at DEVELOPMENT time, running MVC apps and API Apps locally on my PC via localhost.  I don't have a gateway running locally.  There isn't an endpoint listening to localhost/.auth/login/XYZ.

So, what's the story?  How do you authenticate there?  Specifically, how do you develop in such a way that whatever you're going to need to do locally can be Published to your Web and Api Apps and have the auth experience work within the eco-system of the App Service in Azure?

Comment: Possibly similar to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488585/cant-authenticate-with-local-net-back-end

Comment: @GandhaliSamant I'd contend that this is not the same thing.  My question is about Azure App Services released in March 2015.  This new way has your Azure assets sitting behind a Microsoft Managed Gateway that performs the oAuth "dance" for you.  Works great up in Azure.  It isn't clear if anything already exists that can aid/(handle it) in the development phase of a web app or api app, where the code is running locally.

Comment: You can have 2 AD applications. One is for production, and the other one is for development. And then, keep your credential information, such as client id, key, tenant id and sign-on URL, in the app setting of your web app. And similarly, for local environment, you can keep the credential in your System Environment. Now, instead of getting the credential from **web.config**, you can get it from the system environment. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this](https://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/easy-auth-app-service-authentication-using-multiple-providers), the only way to do this is to write some dev-environment-only code to fake `IPrincipals` with claims equivalent to those provided by the Azure environment in production.

> - Create an appSetting value in web.config that identifies whether the app is in local development mode such as:
>
>   ```
>   <add key="EnableLocalLogin" value="true" />
>   ```
> - Define this value in the azure portal application settings as false. This value will overwrite the one configured in the web.config.
> - Create another login option that is only displayed when EnableLocalLogin appSetting is true.
> - The "Login as local developer" button simply calls into an action method which:
>
>   - Checks if the app is in local development mode.
>   - If so, constructs an instance of the IPrincipal class with appropriate claims and calls the ASP.Net Identity systems to assign the identity to the current context.

Comment: Yep.  I found that nothing was available from Microsoft directly either.  While I didn't use the same code that Glav did in your answer, we did end up rolling our own IPrincipal and having some #if DEBUG blocks in our code.  Not ideal, but so far, 17 months later, I haven't lost any sleep over it.

Comment: FWIW - not every application is written in C#, and not every app is using dotnet.

I am facing the same challenge now on a NodeJS mixture of an app, running both server and client sides - whilst using EasyAuth. I also need to use the same mechanism to authorize a Web API call on the backend.

Comment: "Not every app is written in C#/.NET"Sure, but the answer seems to have been what the OP needed, and unfortunately didn't anticipate the requirements of someone else coming along seven years later

Comment: Looks like you might have an option that wasn't around when this question was asked and answered: https://hajekj.net/2020/05/01/running-easyauth-locally/. But otherwise, [it sounds like Easy Auth is about as easy to use locally as it ever was](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux#how-do-i-test-this-authentication-on-my-local-development-machine).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set an alternate login host.  You don't mention the SDK that you are using, but this is generally set by the following:

- client.alternateLoginHost = "https://blah.azurewebsites.net" ([Cordova](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/blob/master/sdk/src/MobileServiceClient.js#L21), [.NET, Xamarin](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/MobileServiceClient.cs#L78))
- client.setAlternateLoginHost(new URL("https://blah.azurewebsites.net")); ([Android](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.html#getAlternateLoginHost--))

Sorry, I don't know iOS Development, but there is [a loginHost field in that SDK as well](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client/blob/master/sdk/src/MSClient.m#L121).