# Access Debug IIS Server From Virtual Machine (VS Express 2013 for Web)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, virtual-machine, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express, visual-studio-express

I'm developing a web site with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web on Windows 7, and I need to ensure compatibility with IE8, so I installed Windows Virtual Machine/XP Mode, and set up network bridging to that the VM uses the same network adapter as the main machine.

Ideally, I would like to be able to connect IE8 running in the VM to the debug IIS server started by Visual Studio on the W7 machine, since having to deploy the site to the actual server every time I want to test a minor fix to the formatting would be a hassle.

The VM network bridging seems to be successful, since I can access domain-only web sites and ping the W7 machine from the VM, but pointing a browser to the site address and substituting the W7 IP for "localhost" comes back with a connection problem, I suspect because IIS is refusing the connection.

Is there a way to configure the IIS process that Visual Studio uses for debugging so that I can connect to it from a virtual machine?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request

Comment: Had tried that before I posted this, actually, no dice.  VM browser still spins for a while then comes back with a connection error.