# iPad compatibility for application developed using visual studio 2012

Tags: ipad, visual-studio-2012, safari-web-inspector

I need to check design and functional compatibility of the software and debug the code i developed using asp.net mvc in Ipad safari browser. I use windows 7 with visual studio 2012. How do I debug my application  and check iPad related issues. I tried to use fiddler but I have no idea how this will help. any ideas can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy website to a development server and access it via iPad. It will help you see how your website look and behave on iPad device.

Here is post that may help as well. [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request#)

Comment: Thankyou for your time :)But I have no problem in viewing the application in iPad after publishing the code.My problem is ,I need to debug it, i.e to see the console errors I get while loading the application in iPad.

Comment: You can try iPad simulator that comes with WebMatrix. http://www.microsoft.com/Web/webmatrix/mobile.aspx

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request#