# ApplicationHost.xdt in Azure Web Apps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, web.config-transform

How to change applicationHost.config in an Azure web app?
I try:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
    Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection webLimitsSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/webLimits");

    webLimitsSection["connectionTimeout"] = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:10");
    webLimitsSection["dynamicIdleThreshold"] = 150;
    webLimitsSection["headerWaitTimeout"] = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:10");
    webLimitsSection["minBytesPerSecond"] = 500;

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

But catch exception:

> Filename: \?\D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
>   Error: Cannot write configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Answer (score 21):

The way to do this is to use XML Document Transforms (XDT) which is referenced [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-transform-extend/).

For your scenario, create a file called **applicationhost.xdt** that contains the following:

```
<configuration  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionTimeout)"
               connectionTimeout="00:00:10" />
    <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(dynamicIdleThreshold)"
           dynamicIdleThreshold="150" />
    <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(headerWaitTimeout)"
               headerWaitTimeout="00:00:10" />
    <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(minBytesPerSecond)"
               minBytesPerSecond="500" />
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

Then, using an FTP client (I used FileZilla), copy it to the **site** folder (not wwwroot) for your web app.

[image]

Finally, restart your web app which you can do from the Azure portal.

You can verify the changes are applied using the Kudu site extension. After signing into Kudu, go to the Debug Console (CMD) window and drill down into the **Logfiles** folder and then the **Transform** folder.

[image]

In the Transform folder you will see a "*scm.log" file that will show the transformations.  It should look something like this.

[image]

Comment: Hello [RickRainey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157294/rick-rainey) - Would you by chance have any solution to this [Rewrite Rule to IIS for HTTPS redirect to HTTP causes null HttpContext.Request.ContentType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871977/rewrite-rule-to-iis-for-https-redirect-to-http-causes-null-httpcontext-request-c)?