# Testing C# Web API on a smartphone/another computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I created a simple web API in VS2015 which I'd like to test on my phone, however, I'm not able to access this API through my private IP address, only via localhost:PORT.

I have read some suggestions which were saying to modify `bindings` in `applicationhost.config` file, but in this file, under `<sites>` I only have one site called WebSite1 which is not my web API I'm testing, therefore modifying bindings in there makes no difference.

**What should I make so that my web API is added to `applicationhost.config`'s `<sites>` collection so I can make it bind to my private LAN address which I can then access with my phone?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options. You could do something like this, built into IIS:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15809698/1883757

Or you could use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

As far as the first route, it seems you've tried a bit of this. Have you tried building your solution, also try debugging it in IIS Express.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding your first point, I have actually seen the answer you have linked, but as I said, I get stuck at the frist point - I can't find the place where to put the `<binding>` since my site doesn't appear in `<sites>`. Regarding building the solution - yes, I have done that ... any other idea what to do?