# IIS Express in VirtualBox port 8081 is blocked

Tags: visual-studio-2015, port, virtualbox, iis-express

I am running Visual Studio on Windows 7 in VirtualBox on Mac.

I can debug my server in Visual Studio (IIS Express) on port 8080 and connect to it from the host. [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

I have the guest machine name mapped to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts` on the host.

Visual Studio (and IIS Express) are *not* run in administrator mode.

I want to have two servers and don't want to have to keep stopping one and starting the other.

However, when I try change the port to 8081, I cannot connect from the host. In this case I can connect from a browser on the **guest**, but not from the host.

The error message is: `Failed to connect to <guest> port 8081: Connection refused`

I have tried to allow the incoming connection in Windows Firewall even though this was not necessary for port 8080.

What is preventing the connection on port 8081?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the port 8081 was not forwarded to the guest. I'm not sure if this is set up by default for port 8080, but creating another forwarding rule in VirtualBox solved the problem.

[image]