# Need help related internal network communication using an asp.net mvc solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, virtualbox

In a new project as frontend developer the team I joined is using ASP.NET MVC for the backend. I am running a mac, so this means I can only compile the C# sources on Windows to run the application locally.

I have a Win10 setup inside a VM using virtual box. The sources are on the host and shared to the guest via a samba share (On `Z:\` in the guest) and a host-only network adapter. Goal is to reach the app then from the host using the IP of the Guest, i.e. `https://192.168.56.102:44301/` (it`s a single page application written in angular)

In the guest I compile from the command line using `msbuild` and then I start the REST API and the "Web App" using `iisexpress.exe`: (because visual studio is way to slow in the guest)

#### commands to build & start:

```
msbuild Z:\TheApp.sln

:: shell #1
iisexpress.exe" /config:Z:\.vs\config\applicationhost.config /site:"AppName.Api"

:: shell #2
iisexpress.exe" /config:Z:\.vs\config\applicationhost.config /site:"AppName.Web"
```

In `Web.config` of the Solution `AppName.Web` I have the following option:

```
<add key="ApiEndpointBase" value="https://192.168.56.102:44302/" />
```

The REST API is listening on port 44302, the "web app" on port 44301

So when I enter https://192.168.56.102:44301/ I get the app served.

### The problem:

For each page reload the web app (HomeController.cs) does an http request against the API, so this means it is internally communicating to https://192.168.56.102:44302/

```
// HomeController.cs
// this fails with an exception like "An error occurred while processing your request.":
private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
...
/// <returns>The index view.</returns>
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
    var response = await clientclient.GetAsync("api/foo?someId=" + someId);
```

`client.BaseAddress` is `https://192.168.56.102:44302/`

So there are two apps running in the guest using iisexpress, and one of them does an http request against the other using the Address `https://192.168.56.102:44302/....` - and this request times out, or fails somehow and I don't get why.

It works if:

1. `<add key="ApiEndpointBase" value="https://localhost:44302/" />`
2. I visit `https://localhost:44301/` in a browser inside the guest

But I want to access it from a browser on the host. Would really appreciate if some asp.net devs may help me here :)

### EDIT:

External requests are already working. Else I would not get the app served on the host. I also registered the URLs using netsh and windows firewall is disabled on the guest. So I think this is not a duplicate of [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

Comment: External requests are already working. Else I would not get the app served on the host. I also registered the URLs using `netsh` and windows firewall is just off on the guest

Comment: I don't get your problem. Why can't you hit it from a browser on the host? Are you getting an error? Is the URL not right?

Comment: Problem more specifc: there are two apps running in the guest using iisexpress, and one of them does an http request against the other using the Address `https://192.168.56.102:44302/....` - and this request times out, or fails somehow and I don't get why.