# IIS Express refuse connection from public IP

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've developed a WebApi server. If I use `localhost:9615/api/method` it works fine. Even if I use an IP address `192.168.0.1:9615/api/method`.

I am very certain that a few weeks ago if i connected through my router with port forwarding like `123.123.123.123:9615/api/method` it worked as well, but now it does not work anymore. I get a connection refused back. Is there something that I'm missing. When I connect to the ip itself the IIS welcome screen comes on which means that the port forwarding works, but for some reason my WebAPI app does not want to accept the connection.

I've changed `applicationhost.config` to accept external connections

```
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9615:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9615:*" />
```

I also added a url reservation with

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:9615/ user=everyone
```

It shows in my reservations as

```
Reserved URL            : http://*:9615/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

From Wireshark it seems like the ACK get send through, but also a RST. Then there is just a lot of retransmissions, and RST, ACK.

Comment: IMHO, more likely, that few weeks ago you had used full IIS and later you switched to Express and forgot that :D

Comment: Never used full IIS. I'm still debugging, and it is just easier in Express

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express by default only allows localhost access. You need to enable external access, see: [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request). You should just use the full blown IIS, not like it costs any money. It's more robust and has more features.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that i've already changed to application.config file to accept external connections