# Connecting to IIS local server via android emulator (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have ASP.NET MVC website that runs on my local sever and I need to check mobile area.

So I decided to connect to it via Android Emulator (AVD)

As I read IIS server reject incoming requests from remote devices.

So from this thread I think I found solution

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971694/8421216)

I make all described on his github and get this

[image]

So as I understood it can receive external requests now.

And I tried to make request from AVD (192.168.2.106:3000)

And I get this

[image]

So as I understood it got path, but IIS still not receive external request.

Maybe someone faced this problem and can help me solve it?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3?source=linkShare-509776cef47e-1505827438

Comment: Yes. I see your answer. Will try it. @LexLi

Comment: I read your article but don't understand many things@LexLi

Comment: For example- How I can add my project to your app@LexLi

Comment: And after changing localhost, how I need to write url in emulator@LexLi

Comment: `http://10.0.2.2:the_port_number` should be the base URL if you use Google's emulators, plus whatever required by your MVC app.

Comment: thank's will try now@LexLi

Comment: It's anyway reject my request @LexLi