# Disable requests from remote users on IISExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

Pardon my ignorance, I read through the below link to enable users to be able access my Development site on IISExpress and then deleted the rules and urlacl But the users are still able to access my site remotely, please advise on how to disable it.

[IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

Commands executed:
Netsh http add urlacl url= https:// 192.....

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=58938 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow

To disallow users did the below:
Netsh http delete urlacl http://192....
Netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=“IISExpressWeb”

Also went to application host config on IISExpress folder and removed the IP address from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS manager  when you are adding your website for hosting, you have one option

pass-through authentication ---> click on  **CONNECT AS**

then one dialogue box will open 
in that dialogue box provide specific user  who can access your site , provide username and password of your pc

and then you are good to go ..