# Access WebAPI running on IISExpress over local network

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I'm running a WebAPI project locally which I would like to access from a mobile device connected on the same network.

I have tried all the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15809698/985012) (where `tower` is my hostame) but it's not working:

```
There are three changes you might need to make.

Tell IIS Express itself to bind to all ip addresses and hostnames. In your .config file. Typically:
VS 2015: $(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config

Find your site's binding element, and add

    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:tower" />

Setup the bit of Windows called 'http.sys'. As an administrator, run the command:
    netsh http add urlacl url=http://tower:8080/ user=everyone

Allow IIS Express through Windows firewall.
Start / Windows Firewall with Advanced Security / Inbound Rules / New Rule...

Program %ProgramFiles%\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
OR Port 8080 TCP
```

Locally everything is working fine:

[image]

However on mobile - I am getting an error:

```
tower's server DNS address could not be found.

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Does anybody know why this might be happening - have I missed something obvious?

Comment: This is not related to your IIS setup. It's that whichever DNS server your *mobile device* is using, it doesn't resolve `tower`.

Comment: Do I need to add a mapping on my router or something similar?

Comment: Probably, but given that this is not programming related, you should really be asking this at https://serverfault.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request)

Answer (score 0):

It most probably means that "tower" has no DNS correspondance so you either need to use the IP address or add the proper DNS entry.

Comment: When I try the IP address - I get:

Bad Request - Invalid Hostname