# Accessing IIS Express from another machine

Tags: visual-studio, iis, webmatrix, http.sys

I want to access the site from another machine, like 192.168.1.**11:10369**

I found a solution for it, that is: http://bendetat.com/access-iis-express-from-another-machine.html

It's working well if I run the project in **Web Matrix** 
But doesn't work from **Visual Studio** and showing Error Bad Request.. http://prntscr.com/ifz2jq (But it is working fine as http://localhost:**10369**/)

What should I do.. so that it can work from **VS** through IP address, as it is working good in web matrix and localhost/

Comment: IIS Express doesn't accept connections from other machines, but you can use our free VS extension called Conveyor to get around that. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
iisexpress-proxy 8080 to 3000
```

> source: [stackoverflow.com/a/29971694/11600278](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29971694/11600278)