# Local C# API, android Studio program

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-web-api, retrofit

I have a local WEB API in c# running in VS17, that runs and accesses a DB in SQL express using the basic HTTP methods.

And on the other hand I want (have the basics of) an android app that is supposed to access the API and just produce a simple GET requests **(currently using Retrofit)** and then display the data that was retrieved. Everything works fine on the back-end (tested with postman).

But I haven't had any success in being able to access my API via the app. Any guidance on where I need to look to or how to start would be great!

> Notes: API is locally hosted
>          SQLEXpress DB is local
>          Android Device is an emulator
>          I need to use SQLExpress as to SQlite
>         private final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:60060";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.pagination_list);

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    EmployeeAPIClient client = retrofit.create(EmployeeAPIClient.class);

    Call<List<Employee>> call = client.allEmployees();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Employee>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Employee>> call, Response<List<Employee>> response) {
            List<Employee> employees = response.body();

            Log.w("MainAct onResponse():", " response method called.");
            if(employees.size() <= 0){
                Log.w("EMPTY", " List is empty..");
            }else {
                for(Employee emp: employees){
                    Log.d("FirstName: " , emp.getFirstName());
                    Log.d("LastName: " , emp.getLastName());
                    Log.d("Gender: " , emp.getGender());
                    Log.d("Salary: " , emp.getSalary());
                }
                //listView.setAdapter(new EmployeeAdapter(MainActivity.this, employees));
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the app to access the API?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to get at, what I know thus far is that you can't access a local API as you would say a https://api.githhub.com, What I think needs to be done is use ports and a local IP, but i havent' had any luck with that (or even being able to check if it did connect or not).

Comment: Our extension Conveyor is generally well received, it makes this possible -> https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a429dbb7-a982-4541-b401-934375c02c0f

Answer (score 0):

IISExpress does not natively suppport remote requests. You will have to do some tweekings to make it work:

Here you got an excelent explanation of how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364468/637840

Comment: I was looking into this,  and wasn't sure if this was still practiced or worked still as there aren't any up to date documentation (relatively) and this will work with VS17 still, widows 10, etc..?

Comment: @Ricardo96MC yes it will

Comment: and so then after i enable remote access i should be able to acces it via the app?