# IIS Express Remote access with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I don't remeber this being an issue before, and many threads are rather outdated now.

On my Windows 10 installation VS 2019 hosts my project at http://localhost:58402 just fine.

However when I go to change the url under **Properties > Debug > App URL** to 0.0.0.0:58402 I get the error:

`Cannot connect to web server IIS Express`

What I have tried:

1. Running VS 2019 as admin
2. Restarting computer
3. Deleting hidden VS folder
4. Modifying `launchSettings.json` in my API project properties folder

I can change the port just fine. But as soon as I change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` the error occurs.

Comment: How remote is remote: is it on the same LAN (use the computer's IP address instead of 0.0.0.0) or is it on the internet in general?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [How to enable external request in IIS Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3313616/1115360)

Comment: Just LAN sorry, yes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have tried all of those answers. The netsh powershell didn't work. The proxy was the best solution but the CORS policy on my devices didn't work well. I'd much rather just expose IIS Express itself to LAN.

Comment: Could you just use IIS instead of IIS Express?

Comment: @AndrewMorton looking into that option currently. Was hoping to just use IIS express to decrease setup overhead when moving computers.

Comment: Deleting .vs folder won't help much, as VS can still generate you an invalid IIS configuration file. Manually edit it, or use a tool like Jexus Manager https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-solution-file. Once you have a valid configuration file, IIS Express should run.

Comment: @Reed Perhaps you could write a small PowerShell script to set up the website in IIS using [New-Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/new-website?view=winserver2012-ps) etc., assuming you have sufficient admin rights on the computers.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I have been using the NPM package iisexpress-proxy with great success now as a daily driver for 5 months now.

Had some difficulty with CORS, but disabling that for local debugging allows me to do everything I would expect.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/iisexpress-proxy

Comment: iisexpress-proxy works great as long as you do not need to accept https requests.