# Why does Conveyor by Keyoti have multiple Remote URL IP Address

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

My machine's local IP is `192.168.1.203` but Conveyor shows multiple IP addresses in the Remote URL IP addresses. What does it mean ?

How can a keyoti achieve this ?

How can a machine have more than one IP different from physical IPs ?

**P.S.:** I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/how-to-enable-external-request-in-iis-express/3364468#3364468) that Conveyor uses reverse proxy, but didn't get this.

[image]

Comment: "Technical support is available by emailing support@keyoti.com." https://keyoti.com/products/conveyor/index.html

Answer (score 3):

If you open CMD and run

```
ipconfig
```

you will see a list of those IP addresses and the network adapters that they belong to.

It's not uncommon to have multiple internal IP addresses like that, and you will probably see that some belong to virtual adapters such as those for VM Ware or Virtual Box for example.

Conveyor actually listens on any IP, and the IP you see in the Remote URL is just one it picked from the available list that should be accessible from other devices on your network.  Sometimes it is wrong and the IP won't work from another device, which is why you see that drop down, so you can manually select the correct one.

Hope that answers your question.