# Use machine-name instead of localhost on IIS express

Tags: visual-studio-2015, localhost, iis-express

I am running a WCF service thru Visual Studio (2015) and IIS Express.

[image]

I can navigate to
http://localhost:50122/TestService.svc

[image]

**What I want to do instead is** navigate to
http://machine-name:50122/TestService.svc

[image]

**How do I configure IIS Express to accept machine-name**, instead of localhost?

What I tried without success:

1. In Visual studio Project / Properties / Web /
   try to change `Project Url` to
   http://machine-name:50122/ but VS prevents this !
2. In the visual studio solution folder there is a hidden `.vs\config` folder. Within it, there is a file: applicationhost.config; I added another binding (second line) with machine-name

> ```
> <bindings>
>   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50122:localhost" />
>   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50122:intel-nuc" />
> </bindings>
> ```

3. If it's useful, both http://localhost and http://intel-nuc both work (default port 80) and point to the default IIS provided demo page - But those are being served by IIS (not IIS Express).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on stackoverflow:
[How to enable external request in IIS Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/how-to-enable-external-request-in-iis-express)
, which also applies to "internal" request.

The command I used (Run as Admin)

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://intel-nuc:50122/ user=everyone

Afterwards, you also need to run VS as Admin.

Comment: If a URL reservation is created via netsh, then you don't need to run VS as administrator for IIS Express to bind to that URL.

Comment: @LexLi theory is different than practice, I actually tried VS without Admin at first, IIS Express would not start, said something about requiring admin permissions.

Comment: @LexLi, to further clarify, I noticed that when I run as Admin, IIS serves both http://localhost:port and http://machine-name:port; (as shown in System Tray). But if I run without admin, only http://machine-name;port starts; In other words, you are probably correct in saying that Admin is not needed, BUT THEN Admin is now needed for localhost !!

Comment: Then you can `netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:50122/ user=everyone` to register to all addresses, without run as Admin at all!